Java Aspect Oriented Programming not working with IBM Liberty server
In my Project I have Simple java with Javax WS RS APIs and Ant build tool is used.
I have created a simple aspect and using compile time weaving. Configuration added in the buid.xml. Configuration looks fine, I cannot share the code as Company restriction.
After creating the war file I have checked the .class files and I can see the aspect.of method coming in the .class files.
But when those pointcuts are triggered my aspect is not printing anything.
When I am using the Runtime weaving , its giving me build error as no configuration provided, but I have placed the aop.xml file inside META-INF folder and that folder is coming in the war file.
Please note that I am working in Java 17 and aspectjrt-1.9.22.1.jar, aspectjtools-1.9.22.1.jar, aspectjweaver-1.9.22.1.jar
So I want to know if simple java with Javax WS RS API and IBM Liberty server are compatible with the Java AOP?

With all due respect: "Company restriction" is a pretty lame excuse for being too lazy to prepare a minimal, complete reproducer. Nobody needs your original code, an anonymised, generic version reproducing the problem is enough.
